# Special case of variance decomposion formula

Tags: probability-theory, expectation

The end of the preamble of the wikipedia page for the [law of total variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) provides the following formula for the variance of $X$ where $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ is the partition of the outcome space (i.e., events $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ are mutually exclusive and exhastive):

$$\tag{1}\operatorname{Var}(X)=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(X|A_i)\operatorname{P}(A_i)-2\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}\operatorname{E}(X|A_i)\operatorname{P}(A_i)\operatorname{E}(X|A_j)\operatorname{P}(A_j)$$

This is given without proof.  I don't quite see how it follows from the variance decomposition formula copied from the same article with variables $X$ and $Y$ respectively renamed to $A$ and $X$ to make them correspond to equation (1):

$$\operatorname{Var}(X)=\operatorname{E}_A(\operatorname{Var}(X|A))+\operatorname{Var}_A(\operatorname{E}(X|A))\tag{2}$$

I think that $\operatorname{E}_A(\operatorname{Var}(X|A))=\sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{Var}(X|A_i)\operatorname{P}(A_i)$, matching the first of two terms on the RHS of (1) and (2), but, while in (1) the second term might be negative (e.g., when $\operatorname{E}(X|A_i)>0$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,n$), the second term in (2) is necessarily positive (since variance cannot be negative).  Thus, I am confused.

Perhaps I am missing something.  Could anyone clarify and/or provide a reference with derivation of (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the sample space be denoted as $\Omega$.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{V}\left(X\right){}={}\mathbb{V}\left(X{\bf{1}}_{\Omega}\right)&{}={}&\mathbb{V}\left(X\sum\limits_{i}{\bf{1}}_{A_i}\right){}={}\mathbb{V}\left(\sum\limits_{i}X{\bf{1}}_{A_i}\right)\newline
&&\newline
&{}={}&\sum\limits_{i}\mathbb{V}\left(X{\bf{1}}_{A_i}\right){}+{}2\sum\limits_{i<j}\mathbb{C}ov\left(X{\bf{1}}_{A_i},X{\bf{1}}_{A_j}\right)\newline
&&\newline
&{}={}&\sum\limits_{i}\mathbb{V}\left(X{\bf{1}}_{A_i}\right){}-{}2\sum\limits_{i<j}\mathbb{E}\left[X{\bf{1}}_{A_i}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[X{\bf{1}}_{A_j}\right]\newline
&&\newline
&{}={}&\sum\limits_{i}\mathbb{V}\left(X\vert A_i\right)P(A_i){}-{}2\sum\limits_{i<j}\mathbb{E}\left[X\vert A_i\right]P(A_i)\mathbb{E}\left[X\vert A_j\right]P(A_j)\,.
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I understand every step except one that goes from the second line to the third: could you please elaborate on why covariance is the negative product of the expectations?

Comment: @HellRazor, We know that $$\mathbb{C}ov\left(X{\bf 1}_{A_i}, X{\bf 1}_{A_j} \right){}={}\mathbb{E}\left[X^2{\bf 1}_{A_i}{\bf 1}_{A_j}\right]{}-{}\mathbb{E}\left[X{\bf 1}_{A_i}\right]\mathbb{E}\left[X{\bf 1}_{A_j}\right]\,.$$ But, the $A_i$ are mutually exclusive, so the first term on the r.h.s. is identically zero.

Comment: Ahh, yes, of course that makes sense.  I wonder if this result is in any textbook.  (I searched my collection and didn't find it...)

Comment: @HellRazor, I'm sure it must be although, I must confess, I can't recall a particular instance at the moment. Grimmet and Stirzaker might be worth a look? +1 for the curiosity.

Comment: Checked Grimmet and Stirzaker's book (found online) but didn't find this.

Comment: @HellRazor, Ah, ... then the search continues. Thanks for letting me know.