# Conditional expectation and variance combining discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, variance

Sorry if my question is trivial, but I am a bit confused about conditional probabilities when there are mixed variables, i.e., discrete and continuous. The problem is the following:

An experiment that is performed $n$ times can yield three possible outcomes each time it is done: left, middle, and right. For this, we use a trinomial distribution to calculate the probabilities associated with each outcome (say $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$, respectively). If the outcome is ¨left¨, then the quantity $Y_1$ is won, where $Y_1$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_1$ and standard deviation $\sigma_1$. If the outcome is ¨middle¨, then the quantity $Y_2$ is won, where $Y_2$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_2$ and std $\sigma_2$. Finally, if the outcome is ¨right¨ then the quantity $Y_3$ is won, where $Y_3$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu_3$ and std $\sigma_3$.

What is the unconditional variance and expected value of Y (i.e., $E[Y]$,$\operatorname{Var}[Y]$)?

I understand that I would have to apply the law of iterated expectations and the law of total variance, but the formulation is unclear to me. Am I correct?

I would really appreciate any help that you can provide!

Comment: Try and write down the formulas for the mean and variance of $Y$.

Comment: @YuvalPeres  Is it something like this? E[Y]=E[Y|X="left"]Pr(X="left")+E[Y|X="middle"]Pr(X="middle")+E[Y|X="right"]Pr(X="right")=11+22+33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that I would have to apply the law of iterated expectations and the law of total variance, but the formulation is unclear to me. Am I correct?

Yes.

> Is it something like this? E[Y]=E[Y|X="left"]Pr(X="left")+E[Y|X="middle"]Pr(X="middle")+E[Y|X="right"]Pr(X="right")=11+22+3

Yes

Let $N\in\{1,2,3\}$ be the trinomial random variable .$N\sim\mathcal{Trinom}(p_1,p_2,p_3)$.

The Law of Iterated Expectation is:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) &= \mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid N))\\&=p_1\,\mathsf E(Y_1)+p_2\,\mathsf E(Y_2)+p_3\,\mathsf E(Y_3)\\&=p_1\mu_1+p_2\mu_2+p_3\mu_3\end{align}$

---

Similarly, the Law of Iterated Variance is:

$\qquad\mathsf{Var}(Y) = \mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(Y\mid N))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid N))$

Now just apply the usual definitions for expectation and variance.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried to do the variance, could you please tell me if my computation is correct? $\operatorname{Var}[Y]=E[\operatorname{Var}[Y|N])]+\operatorname{Var}[E[Y|N]]$ where

$\operatorname{Var}[Y|N]=\operatorname{Var}[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}y_{i}|N]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}\sigma_{i}^{2} $
then 
$\operatorname{Var}[Y]=E[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}\sigma_{i}^{2}]+\operatorname{Var}[\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}p_{i}\mu_i]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}\sigma_{i}^{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}p_{i}^{2}\mu_{i}^{2}$

Comment: Am I right with $\operatorname{Var}[Y|N]=\operatorname{Var}[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}y_{i}|N]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}\sigma_{i}^{2} $? or is it $\operatorname{Var}[Y|N]=\operatorname{Var}[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}y_{i}|N]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}p_i^{2}\sigma_{i}^{2} $ I am kind of confused :/ Thank you!

Comment: It is that $\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid N)=\sigma^2_N$, so therefore $\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}(Y\mid N))=\sum_{n=1}^3p_n\sigma^2_n$.  Likewise, $\mathsf E(Y\mid N)=\mu_N$, so $\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E(Y\mid N))=\ldots$

Comment: I see, then we start with:\\

$\operatorname{Var}[Y|N]=\sigma_{N}^{2}$ and
$E[Y|N]=\mu_N$\\

This means:\\
$E[\operatorname{Var}[Y|N]]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}p_{i}\sigma_i^{2}$\\

Moreover:
$Var[E[Y|N]]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{3}p_{i}^{2}\mu_{i}^{2}$\\

Therefore, 
$Var[Y]=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}p_{i}\sigma_i^{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{3}p_{i}^{2}\mu_{i}^{2}$ Is this ok?

Comment: No. @angelavtc : $\mathsf {Var}(\mu_N) ~{=\mathsf E(\mu_N^2)-\mathsf E(\mu_N)^2\\ =\sum_{n=1}^3 p_n\mu_n^2 -\left(\sum_{n=1}^3 p_n\mu_n\right)^2}$

Comment: Great! Thank you!:)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but on wikipedia, I noticed that there is a special case for the law of total variance when we have mutually exclusive and exhaustive events (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance):
$Var(X)=\sum_{n=1}^{3}Var(X|A_n)Pr(A_n)+\sum_{n=1}^{3}E(X|A_n)^{2}(1-Pr(A_n))Pr(A_n)-2\sum_{n=2}^{3}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}E(X|A_n)Pr(A_n)E(X|A_k)Pr(A_k)$
And I think this could be my case (as the left, middle and right outcomes constitute the whole outcome space). Could you kindly tell me if you consider that this formulation applies in my case? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Besides this question [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133022/special-case-of-variance-decomposion-formula). I cannot really find more information about this "special case". Also, in this question the formula is different than in wikipedia. So I do not really know what to believe.

Comment: Let $A_k$ be the event of $\{N=k\}$:$$\def\V{\mathsf{Var}}\def\E{\mathsf E}\def\P{\mathsf P}\def\S#1#2{\sum_{#1}^{#2}}\\\small\begin{align}&\V(Y)\\&={\E(\V(Y|N))+\V(\E(Y|N))}\\&={ \E(\V(Y|N))+\E(\E(Y|N)^2)-\E(\E(Y|N))^2}\\&={\S{i=1}3\V(Y|A_i)\P(A_i)+\S{i=1}3\E(Y| A_i)^2\P(A_i)-\S{i=1}3\E(Y|A_i)\P(A_i)\S{j=1}3\E(Y|A_j)\P(A_j)}\\&={\S{i=1}3\V(Y|A_i)\P(A_i)+\S{i=1}3\E(Y|A_i)^2\P(A_i)-\S{i=1}3\E(Y|A_i)^2\P(A_i)^2-2\S{i=1}2\S{j=i+1}3\E(Y|A_i)\E(Y|A_j)\P(A_i)\P(A_j)}\\&={\S{i=1}3\V(Y|A_i)\P(A_i)+\S{i=1}3\E(Y|A_i)^2\P(A_i)(1-\P(A_i))-2\S{i=1}2\S{j=i+1}3\E(Y|A_i)\E(Y|A_j)\P(A_i)\P(A_j)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Then would you agree that, for the case of my question, I should use your last formula instead of the commonly applied total variance law? And if yes, every time that I am considering mutually exclusive and exhaustive events I should consider this "special case formula"?

Comment: Update: Well, I just realized that I arrive to the same result no matter which formula I use.